# When to use symbol properties?

Tags: elisp, symbols

Let's say I need to associate symbols with directories, and this will only need to be done for a small number of `boundp` symbols.

The way I see it, there are two easy ways to do that:

1. Store this association in a separate variable (alist or a hash map). This way the directory of each symbol would be accessible with `(cdr (assq SYMBOL my-alist))`.
2. Store this in a symbol property. This way, it would be accessible with `(get SYMBOL 'my-directory)`.

Which of these would be the idiomatic way of keeping track of this information?

Comment: It would be worth indicating whether you know with certainty that there's no use-case for anyone wishing to dynamically bind the values in a temporary scope (as that would pretty much rule out option 2).

Comment: @phils good point. By design it's not meant to be let bound, but I think it's a valid concern. You never know what use cases other people might find for your functions.

Comment: @phils: Just what do you mean? Only the symbol props, not the symbol values, are in question here, no? `(defvar s 5) (put 's 'd "c:/abc/") (let ((s 4)) (message "d: %s, val: %S" (get 's 'd) s))`. And OP: why do you speak of "functions", not symbols? I must be missing something.

Comment: @Drew he meant let binding the directory associated with a symbol. It's not possible if you use symbol properties, but it's possible if you store this information in a variable such as an alist (you just let bind the alist). As for your second question, I said "functions" because all of this behaviour will be wrapped by functions of course. I don't think I've ever seen a package without functions. :-)

Comment: If you two understand each other then no need to explain, but FWIW I still do not understand. By "binding a dir" I assume you mean binding a variable to a dir string. It's certainly possible for the value of a symbol property to be a symbol, whose symbol-value holds the dir string. `let`-binding that dir-string symbol (which is used as the prop value) should not be a problem. (Feel free to ignore if not pertinent.)

Comment: Drew: That's certainly true. My comment was based on the symbol property value being (directly) a directory path string.

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on the use cases.

Generally speaking, symbol properties are "low-level" / "internal" features and one should not use them for "user-level" stuff. However, there is a place for everything :-)

A few points you might want to consider are:

1. Speed: symbol properties are the fastest, closely followed by hash tables; alists are *slow*.
2. It is easier to reset your system (i.e., remove all the vestiges of your package) with alist/hash table (reset the variable to `nil`) than with symbol properties (iterate over the `obarray` and eliminate all the relevant properties from the all symbols).
3. It is easy to dynamically shadow the setting using alist; much harder with hash tables and symbol properties.

Another option you might want to consider is [`.dir-locals.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).

Comment: Good answer. Dunno about #2, however. What do you mean by "reset your system"? Are you talking about the relative difficulty of removing a property from a symbol (vs, e.g., a key from an alist)?

Comment: @Drew: I clarified my point. It is better now?

Comment: Yes, completely clear now. I wondered if you didn't perhaps mean that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the canonical name for the directory, either a hashtable or an alist is functional.  If you expect the user to modify or inspect the data, use an alist.  Otherwise, a hashtable works best and will scale much better.